# Error when calling a function in C# because variable is used in parameter

Tags: c#-7.0, local-functions

I'm new to c#, but I'm trying to create a basic program that can use a function that adds to numbers (this is just practice I know it's inefficient.

```
        {
            int AddNumbers(int num1, int num2) //Here's where the error comes
            {
                int result = num1 + num2;
                return result;
            }

            int num1 = 10;

            int num2 = 20;

            AddNumbers(num1, num2);
```

However, when I try it, it says that "A local parameter named 'num1' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter". I assume that this is because I declared the variables while calling the function, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Just to be clear, the numbers after the functions are the number I would like to be added in the function

Comment: Use different names. Either for the local function parameters or for your local variables

Comment: You have a mismatched number of curly braces (missing a `{`) which would clarify the picture

Comment: @haim770 Again, what would I need to change and to what?

Comment: This is somewhat besides the point, but I would wager a guess that the cleanest thing you could do here is to declare your `AddNumbers` function outside whatever that scope is you provide here (probably `Main` function). Of course, the suggestions by others would also work.

Comment: @ThomasWade did below answer helped you?

Comment: It´s a bit hard to give you a good answer, because your formatting is bad. Is `AddNumbers` a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) that is contained in another function?

Comment: Since he said `I'm new to c#` and `create a basic program` I assume he is having issues with scope which is why it ended up being a local unintended function.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

as you know you cannot have same variable name used in a method
here is what you need

```
     {
        int AddNumbers(int num1, int num2) //Here's where the error comes
        {
            int result = num1 + num2;
            return result;
        }

        int num2 = 10;

        int num3 = 20;

        AddNumbers(num2, num3);

    }
```

you can have something like this:

```
class Program
{
    int p = 0;
  public  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num1 = 10;
        int num2 = 20;           
     int num =  Method1(num1,num2);
     Console.WriteLine(num);
    }

    public static int Method1(int num1, int num2)
    {
        p = num1 + num2;
        return p;
    }      
}
```

Comment: Would like to know why the answer was down voted!

Comment: Why are you creating an instance of Program only to call the Method1? Why not make Method1 static so you can freely call it? using a field + creating an instance of Program is certainly not the way

Comment: @Prix I was not trying to optimize the code here, I was just creating a snippet on fly, if that is why it was down voted then I have modified the snippet. thanks.

Comment: There is nothing about optimizing code in my comment, you're straight up giving the OP a bad example by creating a local field to hold a local sum that is calculated and returned within the method, on top of that you're creating a new instance of the class just for the purpose of calling it.

Comment: @Manjuboyz `Program obj = new Program();` I still see this in your code, you haven't actually fixed things. And prix is right, this isn't just about optimisation.

Comment: A static method is called by using the class name directly, in this case that would be `Program.Method1()` (which is a horrible name for a method - they should be meaningful for what they do). Since you are calling it from within the class itself, you can skip the class name and just call `Method1()' You never need to instantiate the Program class

Comment: My bad, I missed that! have modified now.

Comment: @Manjuboyz you should still rename `Method1` to `AddNumbers` or something meaningful - it's bad practice to have method names that don't mean anything about what they do

Answer (score 0):

Local methods have access to every thing in the parent block. That is why you cannot define the same variable name more than once. Try this instead.

```
{
    int num1;
    int num2;

    int AddNumbers(int left, int right) => left + right;

    AddNumbers(num1, num2);
}
```

There is a guide for this as well found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were trying to make a method for add Numbers. If you want to make a method, you need make method OUTSIDE of the Main code.

```
public static int AddNumbers(int num1, int num2)
{
    int sum;
    sum = num1 + num2;
    return sum;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    Console.WriteLine($"a = {a}, b = {b}");
//First way to control the string: put $ infront of the string, and write code in the {})
    Console.WriteLine("a + b = {0}", AddNumbers(a, b));
//Second way to control the string: put {} and number (start with 0) and write code after comma
}
```

If you write as this, you will get an answer as

```
a = 10, b = 20
a + b = 30
```

For `public static int AddNumbers(int num1, int num2)`
You don't have to think about `public static` yet.
At the position of `int`, you can put another variables such as `string, long, double`. For that case, you have to `return (various you put);` at the end.
If you put `void`, you don't have to put `return` and the thing you wanted will be done in the method.